# How to Externalize the application.properties Configuration in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java

In my springboot 2.5.4 standalone application (not a web application) i am trying to externalize the application.properties (out of the jar file).

Here is the command.

java -jar  app-1.0.jar  --spring.config.location=file:D:\config\application.properties

I am getting error

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Even setting environmental variable does not work
set SPRING_CONFIG_NAME=application
set SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:D:\config\application.properties

Is there any other solution.

[Followed this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Here is the log

```
2023-07-12 21:34:40.984  INFO 8604 --- [           main] com.s7.SchedulerApplication              : Starting SchedulerApplication v2.1.4 using Java 11.0.16.1 on DESKTOP-6NOAC01 with PID 8604 (C:\Users\app\IdeaProjects\scheduler-app\target\scheduler-app.2.1.4.jar started by app in C:\Users\app\IdeaProjects\scheduler-app\target)
2023-07-12 21:34:41.028  INFO 8604 --- [           main] com.s7.SchedulerApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-07-12 21:34:41.435  WARN 8604 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.s7.SchedulerApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2023-07-12 21:34:41.617 ERROR 8604 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.s7.SchedulerApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:189) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar!/:2.5.4]
        at com.s7.SchedulerApplication.main(SchedulerApplication.java:35) ~[classes!/:2.1.4]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[scheduler-app.2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[scheduler-app.2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[scheduler-app.2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[scheduler-app.2.1.4.jar:2.1.4]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:187) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:110) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:67) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:463) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:304) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Just place the `application.properties` next to your jar file and it will be loaded. If you really want it like this please show the logging you have (the output while starting the application).

Comment: You almost certainly need to escape that path.  IIRC you can also just use the other slash and Spring will convert it for you (i.e. file:D:/config/application.properties )

Comment: I have a copy of properties file next to jar file. still spring unable to read the file.

Comment: tried all sort of slash \\ // \ /.. still unable to load the properties file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a SpringBoot 3.0.4 app, Java 19 and placing the `appplication.properties` file in another disk. I had no issue.
I used the same command line as you :

```
java -jar my-app.jar --spring.config.location=file:J:\application.properties
```

Be sure you have right to read the file.

Comment: yes i have read write access